# Comparison operators give wrong results with keyset pagination

Tags: postgresql, pagination

I implemented keyset pagination on these tables

```
CREATE TABLE profiles (
    id serial primary key,
    username varchar(255),
    followers bigint,
    tsv tsvector
);

CREATE TABLE profile_categories (
    username varchar(255),
    category varchar(255),
    primary key (username, category)
);
```

with the following query:

```
SELECT profiles.*, categories,
       ts_rank_cd(tsv, plainto_tsquery($1)) * log(followers) AS rank
  FROM profiles
  JOIN plainto_tsquery($1) AS q ON tsv @@ q
  LEFT OUTER JOIN profile_categories ON profiles.username = profiles_categories.username
  WHERE followers IS NOT NULL AND
    followers > 0 AND
    (ts_rank_cd(tsv, plainto_tsquery($1)) * log(followers), -id) < ($2, $3)
  ORDER BY (
    ts_rank_cd(tsv, plainto_tsquery($1)) * log(followers),
    -id
  ) DESC
  LIMIT 50;
```

The idea is to use `ts_rank_cd` to rank documents with full-text search queries, and to scale the rank by the logarithm of the followers.

The problem is that when I query for the second page by supplying the last rank and id (`$2` and `$3`) of the previous page, I still get the last result from the previous page **as the first result** (so I effectively get only 49 new results)! I have no idea how this is possible since I'm using strict inequality operators.

**EDIT** Even if I cast the ranks to `decimal` the same problem persists -- I get duplicates results at the end of one page and at the start of the next:

```
SELECT profiles.*, categories,
       (ts_rank_cd(tsv, plainto_tsquery($1)) * log(followers))::decimal AS rank
  FROM profiles
  JOIN plainto_tsquery($1) AS q ON tsv @@ q
  WHERE followers IS NOT NULL AND
    followers > 0 AND
    ((ts_rank_cd(tsv, plainto_tsquery($1)) * log(followers))::decimal, -id) < ($2, $3)
  ORDER BY (
    (ts_rank_cd(tsv, plainto_tsquery($1)) * log(followers))::decimal,
    -id
  ) DESC
  LIMIT 50
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by explicitly excluding the id corresponding to the last seen id (the addition is highlighted in bold):

```
SELECT profiles.*, categories,
       (ts_rank_cd(tsv, plainto_tsquery($1)) * log(followers))::decimal AS rank
  FROM profiles
  JOIN plainto_tsquery($1) AS q ON tsv @@ q
  WHERE followers IS NOT NULL AND
    followers > 0 AND
    id <> $3
    ((ts_rank_cd(tsv, plainto_tsquery($1)) * log(followers))::decimal, -id) < ($2, $3)
  ORDER BY (
    (ts_rank_cd(tsv, plainto_tsquery($1)) * log(followers))::decimal,
    -id
  ) DESC
  LIMIT 50;
```

Answer (score 1):

Floating point numbers are subject to representation/rounding errors.  When translated to the client and back again, it is unlikely to be exactly equal to the original.

Comment: That's what I was suspecting. How could I get around the problem? Translating to strings or using more precision are alternatives that come to mind. But I don't think I can do the latter since `ts_rank_cd` is a built-in that returns a `real` number.

Comment: I tried casting ranks to decimals (they are transmitted as strings -- see the edited question for the query) but the problem persists.